# Is there anyways to continue playing audio when camera is opened?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, augmented-reality, html5-audio

I am making an AR based web application for iOS and android devices.

When I use  html to play sounds on the web, the sound stops when AR quick view on iOS or AR scene viewer on android device is opened.

Is there anyways to keep the audio being played even when the app opens each AR viewer?

Comment: If you are using web tech then no. The web browser is controlled by the system, you'd need to turn you web app into an app with Cordova or something similar to play the audio through its own app

Comment: Ahh just as I thought. Okay thank you!